# System broken after I ran sudo apt-get purge 7.0.*

Tags: apt

By mistake I ran

```
sudo apt-get purge 7.0.*
```

instead of

```
sudo apt-get purge PHP 7.0.*
```

Now my system is not opening. What to do now?

I updated the system but still no progress.

Comment: The second command is not better than the first!!!

Answer (score 1):

I made the same mistake a few months ago. The best option you have is to use a bootable USB drive and take a backup of your data. Then you can try to restore Ubuntu.

1. Boot using live bootable usb
2. **Make a backup of your data** (in case something goes wrong)
3. Try to re-install Ubuntu
4. If re-installation doesn't work
5. Delete all directories from Ubuntu root except `/etc/` and `/home/` then install Ubuntu
6. While entering username and password, enter the same username and password same as the old ones
7. Reboot and see if it works
8. If steps 5-6 don't work, then re-install completely and restore from backup

Comment: Why you suggested not to delete etc / and /home directory ?

Comment: because `home` directory contains all your desktop and local configurations files and `/etc/` contains all global configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

(if you mean it won't boot by not opening) There's probably a more efficient solution than this (that I don't know, of course), but I would boot it from a live USB, back up all of your files onto another USB if you haven't already backed your files up, and reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Is there is no way to install all missed application that was purged , because even after upgrading the system i think it only upgraded the available application not the one i uninstalled.  Reinstall is the last option we all have .

Comment: I don't know any way, but that does not mean there is no way.